# Alias or macro expand a template definition

Tags: c++, alias

I'm trying to alias the expression `template<typename T>` or maybe even `template<typename T> T`. Using a macro expansion `#define tt template<typename T>` doesn't work because the preprocessor doesn't know what to do with the `<` token. An alias definition `using tt = template<typename T> t` is a no go either with the compiler wanting `template` to be a typename. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to commit such an atrocity?

Comment: Don't make code unreadable by using some weird macros please...

Comment: While I think it's a terrible idea, [a macro works just fine](http://rextester.com/WXYB85925).

Comment: Other programmers who read your code know what `template<typename T>` means. Why confuse them with your own made up `tt` token? It's not idiomatic.